# appcfg.sh basics. how to compile servlets in command line?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

does appcfg.sh compile servlets or olny deploy compiled project ? If it doesn't how can I compile whole project in the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly recommended to use an IDE to build Java web projects, especially GAE projects:

1. [Eclipse with Google Plugin](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse) (free)
2. [IDEA with GAE plugin](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_app_engine.html) (commercial)

If you dislike IDEs, then at least use maven with [gae plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/).

Comment: It's not necessary just dislike, but in some contexts, e.g. in [continuous delivery](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1621865), command line is the only option.

Comment: Then you should use maven.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by specifying the right dependencies in your master `BUILD` file:

- The binary should depend on everything it needs to run.
- You can create another target for deployment.  That target should depend on the binary, and also on everything else needed to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Google AppEngine supports [Apache Ant](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/ant) for command-line builds. AppEngine Java SDK also includes Ant macros to run `appcfg.sh` tasks from Ant.